# Сделать размер блока зависимым от другого блока

Tags: html, bootstrap

Контейнер `row` в моей верстке состоит из двух смысловых блоков:

- Слева: блок со списком элементов(генерируется динамически от 1 до 10)
- Справа: блок с выбранным элементом

Можно ли с помощью css/html сделать следующее:

Если блок со списком элементов по высоте меньше заданной величины (например, кейс в котором список состоит из 1 элемента),  тогда блок с выбранным элементом должен быть заданной величины, например 400x400.

В случае если блок со списком элементов равен заданной величине или превышает ее тогда оба блока должны быть равными(выравнивание по блоку со списком элементов).

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="container item-list-main">
            <ul className="list-group">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-6">
        <div className="col">
            <div className="card">
                <div className="planet-details-image-container">
                    <div className="view">
                        <div className="Ripple-parent">
                            <img alt='alt' src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x300">img</img>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-body">
                <h4 className="card-title">Title</h4>
                <p className="card-text">
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

На правую колонку задаете min-height, это и будет заданная величина. Когда блок слева будет выше выбранного min-height, тогда оба блока будет одной высоты.

```css
.row {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.col_wrap {
  width: 50%;
}

.col_left {
  background: green;
}

.col_right {
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.col_right_wrap {
  min-height: 150px;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.list-group {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col_wrap">
    <div class="col_left">
      <div class="container item-list-main">
        <ul class="list-group">
          <li>One</li>
          <li>Two</li>
          <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 col_wrap col_right_wrap">
    <div class="col col_right">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="planet-details-image-container">
          <div class="view">
            <div class="Ripple-parent">
              <img alt='alt' src="https://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">Title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">
          Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы уверены в правильности ответа?

Comment: @Nilsan можете написать почему данный ответ неправильный?

Comment: В текущей редакции вопросов нет :-)